# Why we need x-path for finding elements in selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am beginner and using xpath and other locators like name, ID and so on for finding web elements in Web page. Just want to know why we need locators to find out elements.

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You should probably be using css.

Comment: How else would you expect to find elements in the page?

Comment: @JL - xpath is mostly used by those coming from beautiful soup, which is libxml-based. Web browsers, on the other hand, speak css natively, and xpath only as an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

The locators are used in order to interact with the web pages by uniquely identifying elements. However, it is considered best practice to add data attributes specific for the test automation to the web pages, such as `data-testid` in place of using xpath, css selectors, etc.

Comment: This isn't actually true and many of the find_by locators will translate to css. Also, lurk more please.

Answer (score 0):

Locators are used in order to interact with the webelements available on the page. 
For ex. If I want to enter any text in the input field, first I would have to find out location of that input field on the web page and then only I would be able to enter text into it.